# How to set variable in all iframes from parent window using js

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I need to set a variable in all iframes from the parent window using JavaScript.
I'm doing this:

```
for (var i = 0; i <window.frames.length; i++)
{
    if(window.frames[i].test===undefined)
    {
        window.frames[i].test=Math.random();
    }
}
```

BUT! I've got - "Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined" directly in the iframe.

Comment: Yes, given your `if` statement, that's what I would expect.

Comment: maybe you want to invert that :-P

Comment: oh and btw, most browsers forbid cross-site js access

Answer (score 0):

I never have success to put a value on iframe, but i have sucess geting value from outsite iframe and work on it inside iframe.

Try this

```
window.parent.document
```